# Can we remove the NPE from the minecraft error list?

Tags: discussion, closing

The [template answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft) we use to dupe-close most of the minecraft error questions contains a *VERY* basic hint to get rid of a certain Null Pointer Exception.. Also it is just a hint, not even a solution. And this is now being used to close other questions with a (in most cases) different NPE (like [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/338692/minecraft-1-13-1-nullpointerexeption-error-when-trying-to-join-server)).

Can we please get rid of it and instead ask for the Java crash log, which contains the real error message? If the error in that log is already in the template we could still close the question.

Comment: That answer is from when Minecraft was in Alpha and Beta, and thus the advice for Null pointers we have there is likely completely out of date. I'd say go for it! Its a CW post: if you see a problem fix it

Comment: @Robotnik alright, done. :) Hope it's okay this way.